# React doesn't change render according props invoked after a conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator, react-props, storybook

I have a component with a conditional rendering : 'if the component has the prop "showCross" then display a button with a cross, unless nothing'.
Everything works well, when there is showCross, there is the cross, unless there is nothing :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import {Cell} from 'react-mdl/lib/Grid'

class RefundFormContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { fields, onClose } = this.props
    const style = {width: '150px'}

    function CrossButton(props) {
        let {showCross} = props
        const displayCross =
          showCross ? <button
              className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
              onClick={onClose}
          >x</button>
              : null
        return (
            <div>{displayCross}</div>
        )
    }


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Cell col={3}>
                <Formfield {...fields.type} style={style} />
            </Cell>
            <Cell col={4}>
                <Formfield {...fields.provider} style={style} />
            </Cell>
            <Cell col={4}>
                <Formfield {...fields.amount} style={style} />
            </Cell>
            <Cell col={1} className="mdl-typography--text-right">
                <CrossButton showCross />
            </Cell>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default RefundFormContent
```

But the problem is when I use this component in another, even the prop is passed to false, the cross is still displayed (I want to hide it) :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import Grid from 'react-mdl/lib/Grid'
import Form from 'forms/Form'
import {validateCurrency} from 'forms/inputs/currency'
import {makeChoices} from 'forms/utils'
import RefundFormContent from './RefundFormContent'


const RefundForm = (
    {values=null, types, providers, onClose, showCross=false}
) => {

const fields = {
    type: {
        label: 'Type',
        choices: makeChoices(types),
        floatingLabel: true,
    },
    provider: {
        label: 'Demandeur',
        choices: makeChoices(providers),
        floatingLabel: true,
    },
    amount: {
        label: 'Montant',
        validators: [validateCurrency],
        floatingLabel: true,
        placeholder: 'euros',
    },
    comment: {
        label: 'Commentaire',
        required: false,
        floatingLabel: true,
    },
}
return (
    <Grid style={{backgroundColor: '#EEE', boxShadow: '1px 1px 5px 0 #A9A', 
     margin: '20px 0'}}>
        <Form
            component={RefundFormContent}
            componentProps={{onClose}}
            fields={fields}
            showCross={false}
        />
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default RefundForm
```

No error in console, just not displayed as expected.
Through React developer tool I can see that the props is at false as expected, but the display doesn't follow the display condition (that is to say: 'display nothing').
On top of it there is storybook but I'm not sure that this is linked to the display problem :

```
import React from 'react'
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react'
import RefundAssignment from '../account/RefundAssignment'

storiesOf('RefundAssignment', module)
    .add('Affectation', () =>
        <RefundAssignment
            types={['1', '2', '3']}
            providers={['Deborah', 'Patrick', 'Severine', 
'Patrick Swayze']}
            showCross={false}
        />
    )
```

Comment: Try move the `CrossButton` function out of `RefundFormContent`

Comment: This is a nice move indeed, I didn't tried that. But the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem thanks to your answers that put me on the good way :

- The ternary worked
- Props were passed well through components

--> The problem was to define a defaultProps in each component to tell clearly the expected behaviour. (I thought that call or not call showCross would tell if I want to display the cross or not, but no).
So you can use something like :

```
static defaultProps = {
    showCross: false,
}
```

or :

```
const {showCross=false} = this.props;
```

and in the return

```
<RefundCheckbox
   types={types}
   providers={providers}
   showCross={showCross}
/>
```

If showCross = false the cross will not be displayed, if showCross = true it will.

Answer (score 0):

1. move the `CrossButton` function out of the `RefundFormContent` component
2. would be great to see the `RefundFormContent` as well (a jsbin demo would be the best)
3. you use `showCross` in the `RefundFormContent`'s render: `<CrossButton showCross />` but it's not defined via props: `const { fields, onClose, showCross } = this.props`

Comment: 1- I moved the function out of the component but the error is still the same. 2- The first component on the very top is RefundFormContent, actually. But if you prefer a jsbin I will make one. 3-I've added showCross in props but it tells me 'showCross is assign to a value but never used' unless I put <CrossButton showCross={!showCross} />

Answer (score 0):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import {Cell} from 'react-mdl/lib/Grid'

const CrossButton = (props) => {
        return <div>{props.visible ? <button
              className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
              onClick={props.onClick}>x</button> : null}</div>
    }


class RefundFormContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let fields = this.props.fields;
    let style = {width: '150px'};

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Cell col={3}>
                <Formfield {...fields.type} style={style} />
            </Cell>
            <Cell col={4}>
                <Formfield {...fields.provider} style={style} />
            </Cell>
            <Cell col={4}>
                <Formfield {...fields.amount} style={style} />
            </Cell>
            <Cell col={1} className="mdl-typography--text-right">
                <CrossButton visible={this.props.showCross} onClick={this.props.onClose}/>
            </Cell>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default RefundFormContent
```

alternatively, you can only call `CrossButton` if it should be shown using short circuiting, so in the above code the changes to `CrossButton` would be:

```
const CrossButton = (props) => {
        return <div><button
              className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
              onClick={props.onClose}
          >x</button></div>
    }
```

and in `render` of `RefundFormContent` you would use:

```
//...
<Cell col={1} className="mdl-typography--text-right">
            {this.props.showCross && <CrossButton onClick={this.props.onClose}/>}
        </Cell>
//...
```

**Edit:**

To verify that `RefundFormContent` works, just render it as:

```
<RefundFormContent fields={fields} showCross={true} onClose={onClose}/>
```

note that above `fields` and `onClose` must be the props you wish to use.

The above will work the question is, is calling `RefundFormContent` as in the OP, the right way to do it?:

```
<Form component={RefundFormContent}
            componentProps={{onClose}}
            fields={fields}
            showCross={false}
        />
```

There is a mix of props here, if Form is passing the above properly to RefundFormContent, then it should all work fine.

Comment: This is very very interesting codewise but in both cases the cross is not displayed, (in other words it is the exact contrary).

Comment: Edited, please test RefundFormContent independently.

Comment: It's still the same : everything is fine in the RefundFormContent's component, that mean when there is the showcross prop, the cross is displayed and when there is nothing, the cross is not displayed. The problem is on RefundForm if showCross={false} meanwhile showCross is true in is parent, it would be true and  have the same display of his parent.

Answer (score 0):

In `RefundFormContent` you are not passing the `showCross`, but just telling the element to always be "showCrossed"..

Same as `<input type="checkbox" checked />`.

You will to use it like:

```
<CrossButton showCross={this.props.showCross} />
```